# raspberry pi as access point with captive portal

Tags: raspberry-pi, nat, portal, access-point

I recently got a raspberry pi. I have it set up as an access point in a standalone network (not connected to the internet). I can also serve a static website on this network. Ive been trying to set up a captive portal so that when a user joins the network it automatically takes them to this website.

Looking at these tutorials:

- raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md (this is how I set up the access point)
- pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-captive-portal/ (for captive portal using nodogsplash)

So the access point is working but honestly I have no clue about how the captive portal works with this. Im wondering whether the pi has to be connected to the internet for the captive portal to work? If anyone knows anything useful, I will forever be in your debt.

Best,

L

Comment: Not sure if you are still looking for an answer. I have struggled implementing this for months and finally written a [tutorial on this](https://sribasu.com/programming-tutorials/raspberry-pi-wifi-access-point-captive-portal-python.html) when I succeeded. You basically need to update the settings in ```/etc/nodogsplash/nodogsplash.conf``` file so that all requests via that access point is sent to nodogsplash for handling.

Comment: ah cool, i'll check it out. I can't even remember if I ever got this working :S

Answer (score 3):

You can make the captive portal work without internet by adding this to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
address=/#/your.rpi.IP
```

This points all DNS queries to your raspberry pi making the nodogsplash work.